# Installing Sharepoint 2010 Foundation on Windows 2008 Server Web Edition

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to install Sharepoint 2010 Foundation on Windows 2008 Server Web Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751.aspx).
You'll need SP2.